# node.js can't check version after installation on windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I installed node.js version 4.4.1 on windows 10 and I tried to code with tutorial from internet. The first thing recommended was to write "$ node -v", but after that i'm getting following error:

[image]

Comment: Note that the leading `$` is just for documentation to represent the input prompt (shown as `>` in your screenshot). You shouldn't actually type it as part of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already in the Node REPL, not in Windows' cmd (see the Node icon in the title bar?). You can directly write JS in that.

To get the version, run `node -v` on Windows' cmd.

Answer (score 0):

you cant check node version inside node [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) to check the node version you need to exit Node REPL, `ctrl+c` x2 then type `node -v` or lunch `cmd` and type `node -v`